# How to access dataset parameter in query parameter while executing oracle stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, ssrs-2017

I created data-set and trying to execute oracle stored procedure which has one input date/time parameter and three output parameters(One ref_cursor,two varchar).

Stored procedure accepts input parameter as Date/Time datatype and default is today's date.But when I am trying to execute the stored procedure,in the query parameters not bale to see the dataset parameter value created.
[image]

Please let me know how to pass dataset parameter to query parameter and execute the stored procedure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshots, it looks like your using the TEXT query type and not the Stored Procedure.

In the Dataset Properties, you should select the Query Type of Stored Procedure. The parameters should work.

[image]

[MSDN Forums - call-an-oracle-stored-procdure-from-ssrs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f177df1a-4342-4c41-921c-38dc42f1030f/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procdure-from-ssrs-vs-2008-and-pass-2-parameters-to-the-sp-eg?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: I selected the query type as stored procedure and executing.I am not sure what I am missing but the parameter value is not showing in the query parameter dropdown.

Comment: @AMDI - I supposed we have different versions then - when I choose Stored Procedure for the Query Type, the Query Designer has a **Stored Procedure** dropdown instead of the **Command Type** that your screenshot has.

Comment: Maybe.I am using VS2017.